# Planarity testing algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, planar-graph

I want to write an algorithm that takes as input a graph and returns true if it is planar or false if it is not. I searched around and found tons of algorithms but no easy to understand implementations.

Is there any implementation like Boyer-Myrvold's or anything else available in C++ or Java that does what I ask?

Comment: There's a planarity test in LEDA and in Boost.

Comment: Does the graph have a known geometry (already embedded) ?

Comment: The graphs are non directed. Nothing else is specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/graph/doc/boyer_myrvold.html) in Boost of Boyer-Myrvold is pretty understandable and very well-commented.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/graph/planar_detail/boyer_myrvold_impl.hpp

I wouldn't try reading the code without reading the [original paper](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2004/BoyerMyrvold2004.8.3.pdf) first, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a detailed description of the Path Addition method of Planarity Testing in [this thesis](https://archive.org/details/PlanarityTestingByPathAddition) (both the mathematical theory and the algorithmic implementation).

The full Java source code is also contained in the appendices supporting:

- Planarity Testing;
- Generating a planar embedding; and
- To cycle through generating all possible planar embeddings of a biconnected graph (in linear time proportional to the number of edges and the number of embeddings to generate all embeddings).